# Why can't I change the width of my image?

Tags: html

I was wondering why I can't  change the width of my image? For example, if I change the width in the html part of the code nothing happens.

Attempt to change the width in the html, when you change the value nothing happens [Jsfiddle demo.](https://jsfiddle.net/6jagszah/)

```html
<div class="img4">
               <a href="http://s1126.photobucket.com/user/ldocherty1/media/Screen%20Shot%202017-04-12%20at%2018.53.28_zpswixmqbb7.png.html" target="_blank"><img src="http://i1126.photobucket.com/albums/l611/ldocherty1/Screen%20Shot%202017-04-12%20at%2018.53.28_zpswixmqbb7.png" border="0" style= "width="325px height=310px" alt=" photo Screen Shot 2017-04-12 at 18.53.28_zpswixmqbb7.png"/></a>
           </div>
```

Comment: look at the syntax highlighting, and you'll see you've got invalid HTML.

Comment: Because your syntax is wrong.  It should be style="width:325px; height:310px;"

Comment: style= "width="325px height=310px"    you can see an extra quote in there in the middle.   Looks like simple syntax errors.

Comment: @Charlie74 Thanks for your contribution, I also had to include ; at the end of my pixels value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to format your width and height attributes, `style="width:325px; height:310px;"`.

**Replace:**

```
<a href="http://s1126.photobucket.com/user/ldocherty1/media/Screen%20Shot%202017-04-12%20at%2018.53.28_zpswixmqbb7.png.html" target="_blank"><img src="http://i1126.photobucket.com/albums/l611/ldocherty1/Screen%20Shot%202017-04-12%20at%2018.53.28_zpswixmqbb7.png" border="0" style= "width=325px; height=310px;" alt=" photo Screen Shot 2017-04-12 at 18.53.28_zpswixmqbb7.png"/></a>
```

**To:**

```
<a href="http://s1126.photobucket.com/user/ldocherty1/media/Screen%20Shot%202017-04-12%20at%2018.53.28_zpswixmqbb7.png.html" target="_blank"><img src="http://i1126.photobucket.com/albums/l611/ldocherty1/Screen%20Shot%202017-04-12%20at%2018.53.28_zpswixmqbb7.png" border="0" style="width:325px;height:310px;" alt="photo Screen Shot 2017-04-12 at 18.53.28_zpswixmqbb7.png"/></a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'll up vote this when it let's me in three mins.